# Failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in Android Studio 2.0 preview beta 2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle sync fails in Android Studio 2.0 preview beta 2. My project used to work perfectly in older previews, but since preview 9 gradle sync fails with error:

> failed to find target with hash string 'android-23'

I've tried changing compile and target SDK versions but no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with gradle plugin. alpha9 is buggy.

```
avoid 2.0.0-alpha9

use 2.0.0-beta2
```

in your project gradle file.

Works with preview 9 and beta 2 versions of android studio.

Answer (score 1):

> The build classpath specifies which Java source files and resource
>   files in a project are considered by the Java builder and specifies
>   how to find types outside of the project. The Java builder compiles
>   the Java source files into the output folder and also copies the
>   resources into it. The build classpath is specified for each project.

You should use

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2' // or beta3
}
```

**alpha9**

> Sometimes this stage is referred to as a preview version. Sometimes no
>   more features are added after this release, but bug fixes continue.
>   This release comes after a pre-alpha version and before a beta
>   version.

Comment: Then `Clean -Rebuild -Restart -Sync ` .Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

Just change you `build.gradle` classpath with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2` like below while using *Android studio 2.0 beta 2*:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2'
}
```